# Parsing multiple JSON requests in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm trying to parse multiple json objects in ruby.

```
def processKey(key)
   obj = getJSONData(key) 
   puts "got log: " + obj.to_s + "\n"
   @data = JSON.parse(obj) 
end
```

I can see that the obj that I get from getJSONData is correct everytime, however the JSON.parse keeps on returning the first object it parsed

For example:

```
for key1 -> getJSONData(key1) returns obj1 -> JSON.parse(obj1) returns hash1
for key2 -> getJSONData(key2) returns obj2 -> JSON.parse(obj2) returns hash1
for key3 -> getJSONData(key3) returns obj3 -> JSON.parse(obj3) returns hash1
```

Why? Looking around at http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html and  stackoverflow examples I don't notice a way to clean JSON memory or a need to from other exmaples.

What am I doing wrong in regards to JSON.parse?
As a note, I'm using ruby on rail 1.9.3
-Thanks,
Niru

Comment: JSON doesn't remember the data passed in, so the problem is in your code.  We need to see more code. Show us the definition for the `key` values you pass in. Also show us `getJSONData`. We can't duplicate the problem with the little you've given us.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot post the code getJSONData. The only thing I can verify is that each call to the function returns the correct json output. Also the function is really only those 3 lines of code, and there no global/class variables referenced in the function.  Thanks, I did want to confirm that JSON doesn't remember the data passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the mistake in my code. I had accidentally left data as @data, which was incorrect since I had done some refactoring. The correct code within my method should've been:

```
def processKey(key)
   obj = getJSONData(key) 
   data = JSON.parse(obj) 
   return data
end
```

Since @data should not be a instance variable and should not be declared that way.

-Thanks,
Niru